# Apply arithmetic operation from json file to dataframe without using eval function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have json file contains arithmetic operation list to apply in dataframe columns,
I used **eval** function , but i could not use eval function due to security issue, how can apply  arithmetic operation from json file without using **eval** function
my df function will be like the below table:

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 40 | 25 |
| 15 | 10 | 35 | 10 |
| 25 | 20 | 30 | 100 |
| 100 | 15 | 35 | 20 |
| 20 | 25 | 25 | 15 |
| 10 | 25 | 45 | 30 |
| 10 | 20 | 40 | 25 |
| 10 | 20 | 40 | 25 |

````
json_ops_list= {"1":"a/b",
"2":"a+b+c",
"3": "(a-b)/(b+d)",

"4":"(a-b)/(b*d+c)"}
def calculations(df, json_ops_list):
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in json_ops_list:
        col_name = i + '_final'
        final_df[col_name] = df.eval(i)
    return final_df```
````

Comment: Does [this help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)?

Comment: [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) should not have any security issues because it only supports Python expressions and not all statements. @Mohamed Hassan

Comment: @Mohamed Hassan - I looking for docs and no information about securty problem. Why do you think there is there problem?

Comment: I think the user is confused with python `eval` and pandas `eval` @jezrael

Comment: yes, I am confused between python eval  and pandas eval

Answer (score 2):

I think security problem is with python `eval`, in pandas is [no this problem](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#expression-evaluation-via-eval):

> Neither simple nor compound statements are allowed. This includes things like for, while, and if.

Your solution is necessary change for dictionary:

```
json_ops_d= {"1":"a/b",
"2":"a+b+c",
"3": "(a-b)/(b+d)",

"4":"(a-b)/(b*d+c)"}

def calculations(df, d):
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for k, v in d.items():
        col_name = k + '_final'
        final_df[col_name] = df.eval(v)
    return final_df

df = calculations(df, json_ops_d)
print (df)
    1_final  2_final   3_final   4_final
0  0.500000       70 -0.222222 -0.018519
1  1.500000       60  0.250000  0.037037
2  1.250000       75  0.041667  0.002463
3  6.666667      150  2.428571  0.253731
4  0.800000       70 -0.125000 -0.012500
5  0.400000       80 -0.272727 -0.018868
6  0.500000       70 -0.222222 -0.018519
7  0.500000       70 -0.222222 -0.018519
```